# Ошибка при работе с Async/Await в Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, entity-framework-core, асинхронность

Помогите найти ошибку в реализации.

Есть вот такой обработчик события нажатия на кнопку

```
 private void MenuItem_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ShowFrameInBrowser(_videos.Get((int)VideoNames.OSWork).Result.URL);
                ActionsToMakeVisibleBrowser();
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

Который обращается сюда

```
public async Task<Video> Get(int id)
        {
            using (_db = new VideosContext(_options))
            {
                if(_db.Videos.AsNoTracking().Any(v => v.Id == id))
                {
                    return await _db.Videos.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync(v => v.Id == id);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("По указанному индексу не нашлось видео");
                }
            }
        }
```

Результат работы - блокировка основного потока и отсутствие результат запроса. А я хотел сделать асинхронный запрос к БД и получить результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну потому что `.Result` блокирует вызывающий поток. Попробуйте так:

```csharp
private async void MenuItem_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ShowFrameInBrowser((await _videos.Get((int)VideoNames.OSWork)).URL);
        ActionsToMakeVisibleBrowser();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```